# Vue & Vuex: no re-render after object key value mutation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm using vuex store value in front side

```
...mapGetters({ value : 'store/value' });
```

I'm facing a very strange situation:

- If I update de store value like this then it re-renders and updated value appears on front side

```
UPDATE_VALUE: (state, value) => {
  state.value = value;
}
```

- But if I try to update it like, so it mutates the store value but does not re-render

```
UPDATE_VALUE: (state, {key, value}) => {
  state.value[key] = value;
}
```

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, That problem!

That's the weird part of the reactivity system in vue 2, which I strongly recommend you to use vue 3, to avoid this. In version 3, proxies are far more better and understandable.

But, for solution, you can use Vue's `Vue.set` method (or `this.$set` inside a component) to ensure that the change is reactive:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

UPDATE_VALUE: (state, {key, value}) => {
  Vue.set(state.value, key, value);
}
```

or if you like:

```
UPDATE_VALUE: (state, {key, value}) => {
  state.value = { ...state.value, [key]: value };
}
```

Both will work. Best of Luck!